# custom control (spinner) in listview show me repetitious Information

Tags: android, listview, custom-controls

custom spinner in listview show me repetitious Information

I am auing custom Spinner in ListView
Until I don't use custom Spinner it works and shows me title and description  as:

Title 1               Description 1

Title 2               Description 2

Title 3               Description 3

Title 4               Description 4

Title 5               Description 5

Title 6               Description 6

Title 7               Description 7

But When I Use Custom Spinner It Shows Me Information as:

Title 7               Description 7

Title 7               Description 7

Title 7               Description 7

Title 7               Description 7

Title 7               Description 7

Title 7               Description 7

Title 7               Description 7

It Shows Only Last Title And Description.

In Class AdapterNote.Java:

```
package ir.redreactor.app.Com.NovinEr;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class AdapterNote extends ArrayAdapter {

    public AdapterNote(ArrayList array) {
        super(G.context, R.layout.adapter_notes, array);
    }

    private static class ViewHolder {

        public ViewGroup LayoutRt;
        public TextView  txtTitle;
        public EditText  txtDetail;
        public TextView  txtTableName;
        public TextView  txtSort;
        public TextView  txtID;
        public TextView  txtpos;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            LayoutRt = (ViewGroup) view.findViewById(R.id.layout_Rt);
            txtTitle = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitleCS_One);
            txtDetail = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtContentCS_One);
            txtTableName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTableNameCS_One);
            txtSort = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtSortCS_One);
            txtID = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtIDCS_One);
            txtpos = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtPositionCS_One);
        }

        public void fill(ArrayAdapter Adapter, StructNote Item, final int position) {
            txtTitle.setText(Item.title);
            txtDetail.setText(Item.detail);
            txtTableName.setText(Item.nameOfTable);
            txtSort.setText(Item.Sort.toString());
            txtID.setText(Item.intID.toString());
            txtpos.setText("" + position);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        StructNote item = getItem(position);
        final ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = G.inflater.inflate(R.layout.adapter_notes, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        holder.fill(this, item, position);
        return convertView;
    }
}
```

In Custom Spinner Class "CS_One.java" :

```
package ir.redreactor.app.Com.NovinEr;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class CS_One extends LinearLayout {

    public CS_One(Context context) {
        super(context);
        initialize(context);
    }

    public CS_One(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        initialize(context);
    }

    private void initialize(Context context) {
        //
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cs, this, true);
        // Buttons
        Button btnSortCS_One = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSortCS_One);
        Button btnFavCS_One = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnFavCS_One);
        Button btnShareCS_One = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnShareCS_One);
        Button btnCopyCS_One = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnCopyCS_One);
        Button btnSaveCS_One = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btnSaveCS_One);
        // Text Fields
        final EditText edtContentCS_One = (EditText) view.findViewById(R.id.edtContentCS_One);
        final TextView txtTitleCS_One = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtTitleCS_One);
        TextView txtGreenCS_One = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtGreenCS_One);
        TextView txtBlueCS_One = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtBlueCS_One);
        TextView txtYelloCS_One = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtYelloCS_One);
    }
}
```

LayoutRt has Defined At "adapter_notes.xml" So Other Items Defined At "cs.xml"(cs.xml Is XML As For Custom Spinner)

How To Fix It?

---

I used logcat:

```
Log.i("tst", "G.Note.Size Is: " + G.notes.size());
Log.i("tst", "note.title  Is: " + note.title);
Log.i("tst", "note.detail Is: " + note.detail);
```

it show me:

```
04-24 08:27:30.482: I/tst(309): G.Note.Size Is: 1
04-24 08:27:30.482: I/tst(309): note.title  Is: ???
04-24 08:27:30.482: I/tst(309): note.detail Is: hossein
04-24 08:27:30.482: I/tst(309): G.Note.Size Is: 2
04-24 08:27:30.482: I/tst(309): note.title  Is: ??? ????????
04-24 08:27:30.482: I/tst(309): note.detail Is: kurd
04-24 08:27:30.492: I/tst(309): G.Note.Size Is: 3
04-24 08:27:30.492: I/tst(309): note.title  Is: ????? ???
04-24 08:27:30.492: I/tst(309): note.detail Is: 
04-24 08:27:30.492: I/tst(309): G.Note.Size Is: 
04-24 08:27:30.492: I/tst(309): note.title  Is: ??? ???? ??? ????
04-24 08:27:30.492: I/tst(309): note.detail Is: 
04-24 08:27:30.492: I/tst(309): G.Note.Size Is: 5
04-24 08:27:30.492: I/tst(309): note.title  Is: ?? ????
04-24 08:27:30.492: I/tst(309): note.detail Is: 
04-24 08:27:30.492: I/tst(309): G.Note.Size Is: 6
04-24 08:27:30.492: I/tst(309): note.title  Is: ??? ???? ??? ????
04-24 08:27:30.492: I/tst(309): note.detail Is: 
04-24 08:27:30.501: I/tst(309): G.Note.Size Is: 7
04-24 08:27:30.501: I/tst(309): note.title  Is: ??? ???
04-24 08:27:30.501: I/tst(309): note.detail Is: 
04-24 08:27:30.501: I/tst(309): G.Note.Size Is: 8
04-24 08:27:30.501: I/tst(309): note.title  Is: ????? ????????
04-24 08:27:30.501: I/tst(309): note.detail Is: 
04-24 08:27:30.501: I/tst(309): G.Note.Size Is: 9
04-24 08:27:30.501: I/tst(309): note.title  Is: ????? ????
04-24 08:27:30.501: I/tst(309): note.detail Is:
```

it works, but it doesnt show in the list view

Comment: no One can help? help please

Comment: if (c null) {
         c parent, false); What's this?

Comment: witch line? witch class?

Comment: You should know :) It's in AdapterNote, getView()... this won't even compile.

Comment: @elduderino can i have your mail?

Comment: Do you still have problems? I thought you'd found the problem... if you have another problem, please open a new topic :)

Comment: i found it, but another one, so blocked asking question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use:

```
 public StructNote note;
```

and in cycle call it:

```
 note = new StructNote();
```

For Every New note Use

> new ...